# Represent json data with PrimaryKeyRelatedField in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm designing a mailbox with Django. My code is as follows:

```py
#models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User)


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=256)

#serializers.py
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    post = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [
            'id',
            'text',
            'post'
        ]


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'id',
            'text',
            'sender',
            'receiver',
        ]

class MainUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
```

I tried to customize serializer and have a serializer as follows:

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return PostSerializer(value, context={'request': self.context['request']}).data

    def to_internal_value(self, id):
        try:
            id = int(id)
        except ValueError:
           raise serializers.ValidationError("Id should be int.")
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(pk=id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Such a post does not exist")
        return user
```

I want to represent comment objects like this

```
{
    "post":{
         "text" = "Hello"
         "sender" = 1
         "receiver" = 2
    }
    "text": "Greate"
}
```

My code works great but The problem is it doesn't show the Combo Box for selecting the post. I also tried to customize the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`'s `to_represent` method in this way:

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        post_id = super(PostSerializer, self).to_representation(value)
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        return PostSerializer(
            user, {"context":self.context['request']}
        ).data
```

but it says the `unhashable type: 'ReturnDict'` and as I understand we could return anything but simple things such as `int` or `string`. Is there a way to do this?